# facing difficulties in getting contacts in listview

Tags: android, android-emulator, contacts, contactscontract

I am trying to get all the contacts of the phone in a `listview` with `checkboxes` in order to select multiple contacts at a time. I have written some code which is creating the same number of rows as the number of contacts in my `emulator`. But the problem is the name and number of the contacts are not appearing as you can see in the image attached. Moreover when i click Show contacts button to show the selected contacts in `Toast` that too is not happening.

[image]

**custcontactview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="5.0px"
android:paddingLeft="5.0px"
android:paddingTop="5.0px" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cConName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cConNum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/cConName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox1"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_contacts_picker.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Selected" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnShow" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ContactsPicker.java**

```
public class ContactsPicker extends ListActivity {

protected Object mActionMode;
public int selectedItem = -1;
private Button btnShowContacts;
private ListView myListView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_picker);
            myListView = getListView();
    btnShowContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    btnShowContacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String name = null;
            String number = null;
            long [] ids = myListView.getCheckedItemIds();
            for(long id : ids) {
                Cursor contact = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id + "" }, null);
                while(contact.moveToNext()){
                    name = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    number = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " +name + "\n" + "Number: " + number , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
    String[] from = { "name", "purpose" };
    int[] to = { R.id.cConName, R.id.cConNum };
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,R.layout.custcontactview, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> buildData() {
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    list.clear();
    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,null);
    while (people.moveToNext()) {
        String contactName = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String contactId = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String hasPhone = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
        if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0)) {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();
                NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
                NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);
                list.add(NamePhoneType);
            }
            phones.close();
        }
    }
    people.close();
    startManagingCursor(people);        
    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: @LuksProg can you tell me how can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the problem is the name and number of the contacts are not
>   appearing as you can see in the image attached

First of all, I guess you checked and see that you have real values in the `ArrayList` `list` in the `buildData` method.  Second you use the key names `"Name"` and `"Phone"` when you add the values to the `HashMap`, but in the `from` String array that you use in the `SimpleAdapter` you use the values `"name"` and `"purpose"`. In the `from` String array you **need** to have the same keys as you have in the `HashMap`.

> Moreover when i click Show contacts button to show the selected
>   contacts in Toast that too is not happening.

First, you can't use ListView's default mechanism for checked items when you have a custom row view. If you want to get the checked items you'll need to manage the state of the `CheckBox` from the row yourself. The `getCheckedItemIds()` method will not return something valid and the query will fail returning any valid results. Instead you should implement your own custom adapter and return the row's `HashMap`(which will contain the name and the phone) with `SimpleAdapter.getItem` method. This way you'll avoid the need to query the contacts again.

Answer (score 0):

call `notifyDataSetChanged();` You need to refresh the list..